# db2 - export into File

Tags: unix, db2, sh

I'm trying to export the result of a query in db2 to file, but the result like:

```
 +000000869836.|+00000000000001401.
 +000000978137.|+00000000000000511.
```

What can I do to obtain the following result:

```
 869836.|1401.
 978137.|511.
```

My current query:

```
EXPORT TO /tmp/tmp.tmp OF del modified by NOCHARDEL coldel|
select
iv.bpd_instance_id,
max(case when alias = 'abc' then INT_VALUE else null end) as A,
max(case when alias = 'xyz' then STRING_VALUE else null end) as X,
from lsw_bpd_instance_variables iv
where bpd_instance_id in ($instancesDB)
group by iv.bpd_instance_id
with ur
```

Comment: First - what's the actual type of the source data, and (if character-based), what does it actually look like?  Next, the `$instancesDB` suggests you're doing string replacement directly, not a parameterized query, which will potentially leave you open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of DB2's `EXPORT` utility is to format any `DECIMAL` value with a leading positive/negative sign and pad it with leading zeros. To override this behavior, specify the `DECPLUSBLANK` and `STRIPLZEROS` options in your `MODIFIED BY` clause, or `CAST` the `DECIMAL` values to some other type in your `SELECT` statement.